# How to publish same ASP.NET MVC website to multiple location?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing MVC site, that require to be publish for multiple (large number) hosting location (web.config transformation takes care of individual settings), each publish is configure as build profile i.e. Release (Clinet - 1 - US) and it's respective web.config transformation.

I'm looking for an solution to release and publish the project to multiple location using Publishing Profile/Build Profile/Web.Config (respective) Transformation.

Build Profile is already taking care of web.config transformation but I'm not able to figure out how to link publishing profile to build profile and automate the process.

Comment: If your question is how to publish all of these sites at one time, it's not possible with the tools Visual Studio provides. You'll need to look into a third-party deployment solution. Unfortunately, I don't have any recommendations for you in that regard.

Comment: OK. I'm evaluating TeamCity or TFS Build/Visual Studio Online - however they do build but don't push to destination.